# Get the youngest and oldest date within a file inside a variable (bash)

Tags: bash, file, date, lookup

Is it possible to extract the youngest and oldest time from a large file and put into a variable? For example (the original file is without spaces):

```
2020747462 170615095632 984732454353
2020747462 170615143620 278645456456
2020747462 170615103212 192040326564
2020747462 170615035912 139583824564
```

and get

```
Youngest: 170615035912
Oldest  : 170615143620
```

The timeformat (yymmddhhmmss) is on a fixed position in the row. I looked around on the internet but couldn't find any examples or anything like that. I hope there is someone that knows how to to this in bash.

Comment: `the original file is without spaces`? how else shall the fields be interpreted then?

Comment: These dates are in fixed positions in the file. Like 2020747462170615095632984732454353. The positions of the date in this example are 11-22.

Comment: Please post how your original files look like, am assuming without spaces. Update the input example

Comment: Like this (the date start on position: 30)20206458261738NL003133123456717061514561200004726DE838

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cut -c11-22 file \
| sort \
| sed -n -e '1{s/^/Youngest: /;p};${s/^/Oldest  : /;p}'
```

The first line extracts characters 11-22 from the file, the next sorts the output lines, the last prints the first and the last line, prepending the words Youngest and Oldest.

Comment: This works. Only i need to ignore the first 2 in the beginning of the file and the last row at the end of the file.

Comment: @N3tM0nk: So start with `tail -n+3 | head -n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -a -ne '
   BEGIN{$y=9}
   next if $.==1 || $.==2 || eof; # to skip first second and last line
   $y=$F[1] if $F[1] lt $y;
   $o=$F[1] if $F[1] gt $o;
   END{print "Youngest: $y\nOldest  : $o\n"}' <file
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the following is an example with awk:

```
awk '{ dayt[NR]=$2 } END { asort(dayt,dat1);printf "Youngest:\t"dat1[1]"\nOldest:\t"dat1[NR]"\n" }' filename
```

Where filename is the file in question, put the second column into an array called dayt and then sort them by value using asort, putting the results in dat1. Finally print the first and last entries (last entry index signified by NR)